# angularjs ng-repeat not working with slick js

Tags: angularjs, slick.js

i have this code for displaying images using slick.js.

```
<div>
  <slick infinite="true" slides-to-show="4" slides-to-scroll="1">
    <div ng-repeat="var in myArray" class="slick-item">
      <div class="truckImage truck-error"></div>
    </div>
  </slick>
</div>
```

and below is the output.
[image]

if i use three different divs than it works fine but not with ng-repeat.
instead it should come in a single row as originally slick js works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <slick infinite="true" slides-to-show="4" slides-to-scroll="1">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="var in myArray" class="slick-item">
        <div class="col-md-4 truckImage truck-error"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </slick>
</div>
```

I think it will work for you, let me know if it is not working. i have just added  `<div class="row">` and then `<div class="col-md-4 truckImage truck-error"></div>`

Comment: i have tried all this before. did not worked for me.

Comment: could you please put your code in plnkr.co website, by which we can try your code

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding a data attribute to your  declaration

Example,

```
<slick infinite="true" data="myArray" slides-to-show="4" slides-to-scroll="1">
    <div ng-repeat="var in myArray" class="slick-item">
      <div class="truckImage truck-error"></div>
    </div>
</slick>
```